# How to read this kind of json o/p in Android?

Tags: php, android, json

```
[
    {
        "hit": "1"
    },
    {
        "SUM(hit)": "196290"
    },
    {
        "COUNT(id)": "4010"
    }
]
```

how to read this kind of json o/p in android

Comment: Why aren't all the elements of the array of the same type? Every element here has different keys.

Comment: there are 3 queries that m executing...and then i have merge the 3 array into single one and printing that merged output

Comment: You should merge your data from arrays into an object like this:

 {
  "hit": "1",
  "SUM(hit)": "196290",
  "COUNT(id)": "4010"
}

Comment: how to do that??

Comment: Why are you changing the definition of arrays, and complicating things?

Comment: You must first post here what you've tried so far.

Comment: okay... I'll post it

Comment: If you have written the PHP script that produces that JSON, I would suggest aliasing the aggregate functions in your query so that the JSON will have keys without parentheses.

Comment: Also, does your JSON output really have `<br>` tags in it, or did you add those just to format your post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//You can use below code for parsing this kind of jsonarray
String yourResponse;
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(yourResponse);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.lenght(); i++){
     JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
     if(jsonobject.has("hit"){
        String hit = jsonobject.getString("hit");
     }
     if(jsonobject.has("SUM(hit)"){
        String sumHit = jsonobject.getString("SUM(hit)");
     }
     if(jsonobject.has("COUNT(id)"){
        String countID = jsonobject.getString("COUNT(id)");
     }
}
```